# C# to Excel insert record as decimal instead of text

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms

I am inserting data into an Excel file from my C# program using OLEDB connection. All fields are inserted as text but I want `AMOUNT` field to be inserted as decimal into the Excel file. My code:

```
OleDbConnection conOledb;
OleDbCommand cmdOledb = new OleDbCommand();

conOledb = new OleDbConnection(" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + destFile + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'");

string sqlQuery = "Insert into [Sheet1$] ([Record Identifier],[Payment Value Date],[Product Code],[Debit Account Number],[Beneficiary Name],[Instrument Amount],[Beneficiary Bank IFSC Code ],[Beneficiary Account Number],[Remarks1],[Remarks2]) " +
                  "  VALUES(@MODE, @DATE, @RTGS, @OURBANKACC, @PARTYNAME, @AMOUNT, @RTGSCODE, @PARTYBANKACC, @PARTYNAME, @NARRATION1)";

conOledb.Open();
cmdOledb.Connection = conOledb;
cmdOledb.CommandText = sqlQuery;
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODE", 'P');
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", Convert.ToDateTime(dt_From.EditValue).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RTGS", (row["RTGS"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OURBANKACC", (row["OURBANKACC"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTYNAME", (row["PARTYNAME"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", Convert.ToDecimal(row["AMOUNT"] ?? 0));
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RTGSCODE", (row["RTGSCODE"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTYBANKACC", (row["PARTYBANKACC"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARTYNAME", (row["PARTYNAME"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());
cmdOledb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NARRATION1", (row["NARRATION1"] ?? string.Empty).ToString());

cmdOledb.ExecuteNonQuery();
conOledb.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try to specify the parameter type? Such as: cmdOledb.Parameters.Add("@AMOUNT", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row["AMOUNT"] ?? 0);

Comment: Yes i tried but same result  getting TEXT in excel file

Comment: While inserting records into a database, the column types are pre-defined. Same is for the excel databases as well. Open your excel file, Select the Instrument Amount column and change the column type to "Number" with desired decimal places. Then your insert will work

Comment: i tried but same result as previous

Comment: I tried that with command parameter type currency and it worked

Comment: Another option is to use EPPlus instead of OLEDB to produce a workbook with full formatting, cell types etc. You also avoid all hassles related to OLEDB drivers. Loading data can be as simple as calling `sheet.LoadFromDataTable()` or `LoadFromCollection`

Comment: I have predefined Excel sheet in which i am inserting record Here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DA4JgrYJyYc1RoRTBiZFB1MGc/view?usp=sharing